# Bootstrap DatePicker 3 show multiple months

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using **Bootstrap 3 Datepicker** [Homepage](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/)

And it's working great but I need to show two months instead of one. I know in the options tab they show **sideBySide** events but it's for the time only, I would like to show another month there instead of the time.

Can anyone help with this?

This is what it shows with sideBySide

[image]

But I need it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a range date picker, and if I'm right this plugin doesn't have such functionality.
You can use something like [this](http://www.daterangepicker.com)
Instead.

Comment: Maybe hahaha. I'm from Brazil and as far as I know my surname came from some family In Portugal.

Comment: The daterangepicker is not the solution. It offers 2 independent datepicker, for selcting 2 differnt dates.

I think, there should only be displayed a second month to offer more usability when selcting dates.

Answer (score 1):

<s>This 'll do</s> Bootstrap date-picker doesn't have this functionality, but this can be easily done using [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars)

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2
        });
    } );
</script>


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: There is not such property in bootstrap-datepicker. Please post a link to the documentation.

Comment: The 'numberOfMonths' is a properety of the jQuery datepicker. It is not available in the datepicker of bootstrap.

Comment: I upvoted this, but I was using jQuery datepicker, haha.

Comment: @Sridhar-Srivinx is it works together with bootstrap-datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the game, but here is my solution: use multiple calendars (tested with Tempus Dominus, should work with bootstrap-datepicker too):

```
=== HTML Part: ===
<div class="row" id="datetimepicker1"></div>
<div class="row" id="datetimepicker2"></div>

=== Javascript Part: ===

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    inline: true
});

$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    inline: true,
    defaultDate: moment().add(1, 'months')
});


$("#datetimepicker1").on("update.datetimepicker", function (e) {
    e.viewDate.add(1, 'months');
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker('date', e.viewDate);
});
```

Beware of a bug which prevents "update.datetimepicker" from firing: https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/issues/176